# remove the character instance from string problem with remove

Tags: c++, c++14

I am facing a problem in removing all instances of a character from a string. As removal of characters is based on a loop condition, the results produced by C++ string function erase(or remove) are different. Have a look at the code:

```
int main()
    {
        string s="beabeefeab";
        string s2=s;
        cout<<"s[0] "<<s[0]<<endl;
        s.erase(remove(s.begin(),s.end(),'b'),s.end());   //statement 1
        cout<<s<<endl;
        s=s2;
        s.erase(remove(s.begin(),s.end(),s[0]),s.end());  //statement 2
        cout<<s<<endl;
        return 0;
    }
```

The output produced by statement 1 and statement 2 should be the same but turn out to be different. How and why?

Comment: What output did you expect?

Comment: the output should be 'eaeefea' in both the statements but statement 2 is producing some abrupt result.

Comment: Try outputting `s[0]` before your second erase/remove statement. That should tell you what you are about to remove.

Comment: If the topvoted answer correctly guesses what you mean, you should clarify that the statements are not consecutive in a single problem, but you mean them as an alternative implementations.

Comment: @BartoszKP thanks for correcting me, and yes they are separate implementations. I have done the corrections in the code.

Comment: @SoumilKhandelwal Thanks, now it's clear. I took liberty of focusing your question on this one particular issue you had in mind. Hope it still correctly describes what you intended! :)

Answer (score 6):

If I understand correctly you want to see the same output string executing two below codes:

```
[1]
s = "beabeefeab";
s.erase(remove(s.begin(),s.end(),'b'),s.end());   //statement 1
cout << s << endl; // eaeefea

[2]
s = "beabeefeab";
s.erase(remove(s.begin(),s.end(),s[0]),s.end());  //statement 2
cout << s << endl; // should be eaeefea
```

you can achive it by casting `s[0]` to Rvalue - `(char)s[0]`.

Third parameter of remove algorithm is `const T&`. When you pass `'b'` - Rvalue is bound to  `const char&` and it is valid for the whole execution of `remove` algo. When you pass `s[0]` - Lvalue, Lvalue is bound to `const char&` parameter of algo, but at the first remove operation the value of first item pointed to by reference is changed, and remove algo fails.

Comment: IMHO, this is the answer the OP was looking for. Follow-up question: when passing `s[0]` as an lvalue, is the reference really invalidated? I think it will continue referencing the first element, which - after the first shift towards the end of the string in statement 2 - is 'a'. That's why the result of statement 2 is 'aeefe' (at least on my machine).

Comment: Yea, you are right, I used incorrect words to express my idea :) Of course, reference is valid, but it points to item whose values was changed.

Comment: OP probably needs to clarify... They have stated they expect the outputs of statement 1 and 2 to be the same, but that could be a false expectation based on a misunderstanding of what `s[0]` is referring to during the lifetime of their application.

Comment: Also, you appear to have introduced a different line into your answer than what the OP has. The OP isn't resetting s to "beabeefeab" before performing statement 2.

Comment: yes, I made a mistake there, I have made the corrections in the code, they are separate implementations, @lubgr, even so If I haven't reset the value, then all the instances of next reference of s[0] i.e. 'e' should have been removed but they are appearing in the output. Can you please explain the reason for this.

Comment: @rafix07 , I have made the corrections and you interpreted the problem as I wanted to ask.

Comment: @Ralara, I have made the corrections in the code, they are seperate implementations.

Answer (score 0):

With the first erase/remove you remove `'b'`. That will leave `s[0]` to be equal to `'e'`.

You then pass that `'e'` to the second erase/remove, which means you remove it too.

Comment: I have made some corrections in the code, they are two separate implementations, please have a look and express your answer. And yes You are right here, but even so when I execute the second statement, all the instance of  'e' are not removed. Can you please explain this.

Comment: @SoumilKhandelwal Please don't modify code like that. That makes existing comments and answers useless. Add a new section *below* the current text (separated by a triple dash `---`) with the new code. Unless the answers actually answers your current question and you have a *new* question, in which case you should *post* a new question.

Comment: I will keep that in mind, as I am new to StackOverflow please correct me if I make any mistake. And help with the code.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude No, in this case what OP did was correct. The first version of the question was just a poor formulation of their intent. What OP did was not *changing* the question - this was *fixing* the question.